# driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint clickstre

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have two docker containers  and I want to make them visible to each other.

1 container: Collector(it collects pagaviews on the sites and send to kafka clucster)
2 container: kafka cluster

I wrote docker-compose file:

```
             version: "2"

             services:

             kafka-cluster:
             image: landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0
             environment:
             ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1         # Change to 192.168.99.100 if using Docker Toolbox
             RUNTESTS: 0                 # Disable Running tests so the cluster starts  faster
ports:
  - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
  - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
  - 8081-8083:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
  - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
  - 9092:9092

csapi:
   build:
     context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
   links:
    - kafka-cluster
```

The docker-compose up command gives me  the error: Creating clickstream-collector_kafka-cluster_1 ... error

ERROR: for clickstream-collector_kafka-cluster_1  Cannot start service kafka-cluster: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint clickstre

Answer (score 0):

Links are deprecated. Please refer to the Docker networking documentation

You simply would use `kafka-cluster:9092` since all containers already know about one another by name when using Compose

Regarding your error, it doesn't appear to have anything to do with Kafka, but I suggest you use separate containers for Zookeeper and Kafka as well as use a newer version of Kafka so you may benefit from enhanced features and fixes

You definitely should be be advertising 127.0.0.1, though if you research that setting a bit (plus advertised hostname property is deprecated for advertised *listeners*)